# Is it possible to update a For End argument while inside it?

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to change my For "End" argument while inside the For.

For instance:

```
ForEnd = 3
for i = 1 To ForEnd
   If Something = "TRUE" Then
      ForEnd = ForEnd + 1
   End If
Next i
```

This doesn't work because the "End" or "Upper Limit" argument is defined once the code goes through the first line. Even if I change it inside the code it will consider the original value.

Any thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: Why you don't use a while loop ?

Comment: BTW It should be `Next i` not `Next ForEnd`

Comment: Thought what Olf said is the way to go in this case, maybe giving us a bit more info on your goals might help giving you a specific approach to your problem. As for your code goes, there is no need to do that. Why do you need to increase the ending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Olff, replace the for-loop by a while-loop:

```
ForEnd = 3
i = 1

while i<ForEnd
   If Something = "TRUE" Then
      ForEnd = ForEnd + 1
   End If
   i = i + 1
Wend
```

Be very careful not ending up in an infinite loop! (`Something` needs to be different than `"TRUE"` regularly)

Another way to go (a more modern approach) is using the `Do..Loop` approach:

```
ForEnd = 3
i = 1

Do While i<ForEnd
   If Something = "TRUE" Then
      ForEnd = ForEnd + 1
   End If
   i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: `While...Wend` is deprecated, and `While...Do...Wend` is an invalid construct.

Comment: It's a holdover from the original BASIC syntax. The page you've linked to recommends `Do...Loop` instead, which supersedes it.

Comment: @jsheeran: you're right, I've adapted my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you need to increase the ending, and why you cannot use other options as `Do...Loop`, but this migh work for you. Try to adapt it to your needs:

```
Dim ForEnd As Byte 'Limit or FOR...NEXT
Dim i As Byte 'Counter of FOR...NEXT
Dim XX As Byte 'It will store the last value of i when we restart the FOR...NEXT
Dim Something As String

ForEnd = 3
XX = 1 'First value of i

For_Start:

For i = XX To ForEnd Step 1
    If Something = "TRUE" Then
        ForEnd = ForEnd + 1
        XX = i + 1
        GoTo For_Start
    End If

Next i
```

You handle with another variable the last position of your loop, and restart it from there with a `GoTo`

Answer (score 0):

You can not control the upper limit of a `For` cycle when you use a const or a variable in the heading. However, using a function will do this:

```
for i = 1 To ForEnd(i)
      ' commands
Next i

Function ForEnd(k as Long) As Long

     If Something = "TRUE" Then
        ForEnd = 0
     Else
        ForEnd = k + 1
     End If

End Function
```

though I'd rather use `Do While` as above. If you need `For` loop then you can use `Exit For` to break the loop in case:

```
for i = 1 To 111111
    If Something = "False" Then Exit For
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim i As Long

    i = 1

    Do Until i > 6

        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = 20

        i = i + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```